# Using ASP.Net MVC routing to bind parameter x to y

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm upgrading an application from web forms to MVC. I was trying to handle incoming legacy requests (`default.aspx?param1=[guid]`) and route them to the new controller (`new/param2=[guid]`). I cannot change the incoming requests as these are not controlled by our application. Also I cannot change the param2 to param1 as this new controller action is being used by other applications.

I have the following route which seems to route the requests to the new controller but I'm unable to get the parameter to bind

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "LegacyDefault",
        "default.aspx/{param1}", 
        new {controller = "new", action = "Index", param2 = UrlParameter.Optional}
    );
```

This however, doesn't bind param2 as it doesn't exist in the request. Is there any easy and elegant way to route param1 in the request to param2 using only the RouteConfig?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the URL Rewrite module in IIS. Far more flexible, quicker, and doesn't require bastardizing your codebase to support legacy URLs.

See: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module